# L-stable discretization method with optimal stability region

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, dynamical-systems, control-theory

I am looking for discretization methods of continuous linear time invariant systems with the properties:

1. It is L-stable (meaning it is A-stable and its stability function approaches zero in the limit)
2. It maps the open left half of the complex s-plane to the interior of the unit circle of the z-plane.

Some background: Consider the system

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}(t) &= f(t,x(t))  \\
 x(0) &= x_0
\end{align}\tag{1}
$$

where $f:R^m\to R^m$ is smooth and $x\in R^m$. A numerical solution to the initial value problem $(1)$ can be computed by the general (potentially implicit) Runge-Kutta method of order $s$ and step-witdth $h$:

$$
\begin{align}
x_{n+1} &= x_n + h \sum_{i = 1}^s b_i k_{ni} \\
k_{ni} &= f\Big(t_n + c_i h, x_n + h \sum_{j = 1}^s a_{ij}k_{nj}\Big)
\end{align} \tag{2}
$$

The coefficients $a_{ij},b_i,c_i$ in $(2)$ are defined by the Butcher tableau:

$$
\begin{array}
{c|c}
c & A  \\
\hline
& b^T
\end{array}=
\begin{array}
{c|cccc}
c_1 & a_{11} & a_{12} & \dots & a_{1s} \\
c_2 & a_{21} & a_{22} & \dots & a_{2s} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
c_s & a_{s1} & a_{s2} & \dots & a_{ss} \\
\hline
& b_1 & b_2 & \dots & b_s
\end{array}
$$

Different methods have different Butcher tableaus. For example:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Method} & \text{Butcher tableau} \\ \hline
\text{Explicit Euler} & A = 0, b = 1, c = 0 \\ \hline
\text{Implicit Euler} & A = 1, b = 1, c = 1 \\ \hline
\text{Heun} & A = \begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}, b = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}\\ \frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}, c = \begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\end{pmatrix}  \\ \hline
\text{Runge Kutta 4} & A = \begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&0\\\frac{1}{2}&0&0&0\\ 0&\frac{1}{2}&0&0\\0&0&1&0 \end{pmatrix}, b = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{6}\\\frac{1}{3}\\ \frac{1}{3}\\ \frac{1}{6}\\ \end{pmatrix}, c = \begin{pmatrix}0\\ \frac{1}{2}\\ \frac{1}{2} \\ 1\end{pmatrix} \\ \hline
\text{Trapezoidal} & A = \begin{pmatrix}0&0\\ \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}, b = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}\\ \frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}, c = \begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\end{pmatrix} \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

Each method has a stability region $S$ which is given by

$$
S = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |\phi(z)| \leq 1 \} \tag{3}
$$

In Eq. $(3)$ the function $\phi$ is the stability function of the considered method which is constructed from its Butcher tableau:
$$
\phi(z) = \frac{\det(I - z A + z \mathbf{1} b^T)}{\det(I - z A)} \tag{4}
$$
Here $I$ is $s \times s$ identity matrix and $\mathbf{1}$ a $s \times 1$ vector of ones. The stability regions (in yellow) for the five methods look like this:

[image: Stability Regions]

Now define **A-stability**: A method is A-stable if its stability region contains the left half-plane of $\mathbb{C}$, meaning that $\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : Re(z) \leq 0 \} \subset S$. Here $Re(z)$ is the real part of $z$.

As can be seen in the plots above, out of the the five example methods, only the implicit Euler and the trapezoidal method are A-stable.

Now define **L-stability**: A method is L-stable if it is A-stable and if
$$
\lim_{Re(z) \rightarrow -\infty} |\phi(z)| = 0
$$

*Note*: A-stability and L-stability are different concepts than asymptotic stability and Lyapunov stability (the naming is a bit unfortunate in my opinion).

To come back to my question, I am looking for a method that is L-stable (1. condition) and whose stability region is exactly the left half of the complex plane (2. condition). In other words, I am looking for a L-stable method with stability region $S = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : Re(z) \leq 0 \}$.

For example the billinear transform (trapezoidal method) satisfies the second condition. However its stability function $\phi$ satisfies

$$
\lim_{Re(z) \rightarrow -\infty} |\phi(z)| = \lim_{Re(z) \rightarrow -\infty} \Big|\frac{1 + 0.5 z}{1 - 0.5z}\Big| = 1 \neq 0
$$

So it is not L-stable.

On the other hand, the implicit Euler method is L-stable because

$$
\lim_{Re(z) \rightarrow -\infty} |\phi(z)| = \lim_{Re(z) \rightarrow -\infty} \Big|\frac{1}{1 - z}\Big| = 0
$$

However it doesn't satisfy the second condition because its stability region is "larger" than the left half of the complex plane.

**Question**: Is there a method that has both properties?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by L-stable and A-stable? Are you referring to Lyapunov-stable and asymptotically stable?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen I updated the question.

Comment: Did you consult the appropriate section IV.3 "Stability ..." of Hairer/Wanner: "Solving ODE II"? For instance in exercise 7 a composite $\theta$ method is proposed that has order 2 and was proven as effective in fluid simulations. The surrounding discussion shows that even to get a handle on a formulation for the balance of these desired property is non-trivial.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on the second part? What are the mathematical formulas expressing this?

Comment: @DanDoe Hi, what exactly do you mean by "second part"? I have given the precise definitions of stability and formulas for both the stability region and the stability function, so I don't really know what more to add?

Comment: "2. It maps the open left half of the complex s-plane to the interior of the unit circle of the z-plane."

Comment: @DanDoe Assume $f$ is linear and time invariant such that $\dot{x}=Ax$. Using a discretization method (like eg RK4), this continuous system can be converted to a discrete system like $x_{k+1}=\Phi x_k$, where $\Phi$ depends on $A$ and the discretization method. With the second point I mean that the discretization method should be such that $\Phi$ is Schur if and only if $A$ is Hurwitz.